# IDEAでKotlinのBool変数を反転させるコードを書くと"Redundant 'if' statement"という提案が表示される

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

**環境**
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4
Kotlin 1.2.30
Windows 10 64bit

下記のようなBool値を反転させるコードを書くと、`Redundant 'if' statement`という提案が表示されます。

```
class Foo {
    private var boolVar = false

    fun doSomething() {
        if (boolVar) {
            boolVar = false
        } else {
            boolVar = true
        }
    }
}
```

提案の詳細は下記の通りです。

```
Redundant 'if' statement
Reports if statements which can be simplified to single statements.
For example:
    if (foo()) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

can be simplified to
    return foo()
```

提案の内容はわかるのですが、元コードとの関連がわかりません。
なぜこの提案がされるのかと、改善方法について、何かわかりませんか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

提案の例は「ifの評価式でtrue/falseが決まるなら、`if～else`はわざわざ書かず、直接評価式の結果を返せばいいのでは？」と読めます。

実際のコードでは(元の)boolVarの反転を取ればいいようなので、`!`を使って以下の様に書き換えられるのではないでしょうか。

```
fun doSomething() {
    boolVar = !boolVar
}
```

Comment: 提案が出なくなりました。ありがとうございます